# postgres column name ending with "_id" not possble?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am using django and postgres for my app. I was trying to make a postgres table containing columns ending with "_id" to mimic relation table. Postgres made the column name the one without "_id".

For example,

```
class Math(models.Model):

    student_id = models.IntegerField()
    teacher_id = models.IntegerField()
    test_time = models.DateTimeField()
    test_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

In postgres table, it turned out to be the column names of School table changed to;

```
student
teacher
test_time
test_id
```

I guess postgres does not allow me to assign column name ending with "_id" at least for the IntegerField(). Is there any way to get around of this limitation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html I don't know django. but id is not reserved word.

Comment: This is a `Django` thing not a `Postgres` one: `create table id_naming (student_id integer, teacher_id integer) \d id_naming student_id | integer, teacher_id | integer`. My guess because `Django` uses `_id` for [Foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#database-representation).

Comment: Thanks Mark and Adrian! I am googling with django postgres id_naming, but could not find good documentations. Can you please give me a link about your solution?

Comment: You could try: `student_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='student_id')`. Not sure whether this will play well with Django's use of `_id`.